# Is it safe to end a destructor with a return statement?

Tags: c++, destructor

In my doubly-linked list class, I am coding my destructor and this is my code:

```
DLinkedList::~DLinkedList() {
    if (head==NULL) {
        return;
    }

    // Other code
}
```

Is it safe to end a destructor with a `return;` statement?

I know that I can end my `void` functions with a `return;` statement, but this is a destructor.

Comment: Yes, it's no worse than ending a `void` function early. But depending on what the `//other code` is, you might be able to rewrite your destructor so that the `if` is not needed at all.

Comment: It's OK for early out. However, I sometimes read that certain programmers consider early out as bad style. I personally think, cascades of nested `if`s are not that much better. So, it might be a matter of taste. I found a Q/A in SE about this: [SE: Should I return from a function early or use an if statement?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/18454) Consider that it has been closed due to _primarily opinion-based_... ;-)

Comment: Normative reference: http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#2

Comment: The structured programming paradigm frowns on early return.  For my C++ code, I return whenever it is appropriate, but there are lots of C++ folks who try hard to make their code only return at the very end.  I presume they were taught that habit, and adhere to it.  (Exceptions being an exception, I suppose, since they're another return path.)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming

Comment: Let me answer your question with another question: Why would you think it might not be safe? Did you think that it might return 'more' than hitting the closing brace would, and thus skip something that would normally happen after the destructor body? If "safe" is just a misnomer for 'valid code that a compiler should accept', then you should just turn on warnings to know that.

Comment: But why?  Consider:  "if ( doNother() )  {  other code  }", no cascades ...  So your opinion is ...

Comment: Hint: destructors *are* `void` functions. The (likely) reason we don’t specify `void` as the return type is because they cannot be anything else but `void`, so why bother? Bjarne Stroustrup could have required to always prefix destructor declarations with `void` instead; that was simply a style choice. I checked “The Design and Evolution of C++” book but I didn’t find a reasoning. I suspect he felt that specifying `void` would have been redundant.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Is it safe to end a destructor with `return;` statement? I know that I can end my `void` functions with a `return;` statement, but this is a destructor.

There's not much difference of a destructor function from a function with `void` return type, besides the destructor function is executed automatically<sup>1</sup> whenever the class's lifetime ends.

You use `return;` if the execution of the destructor function should be stopped, as you do with any other function.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>The same applies for constructor functions BTW.</sub>

Answer (score 12):

**Yes.**

In this sense, the destructor body acts much like a function that returns `void`, except that the bases and members will still be destroyed even if you `return` early (since this never relied on the contents of the destructor body anyway).

Observe the following rules:

> [`[special]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/special#1): The default constructor (`[class.default.ctor]`), copy constructor, move constructor (`[class.copy.ctor]`), copy assignment operator, move assignment operator (`[class.copy.assign]`), and destructor (`[class.dtor]`) are special member functions. *[..]*
>
> [`[stmt.return]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.reutnr#1): A function returns to its caller by the `return` statement.
>
> [`[stmt.return]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#2): The *expr-or-braced-init-list* of a `return` statement is called its operand. A `return` statement with no operand shall be used only in a function whose return type is *cv void*, a constructor, or a destructor. *[..]*
>
> [`[class.dtor]/9`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#9): *[..]* A `return` statement (`[stmt.return]`) in a destructor might not directly return to the caller; before transferring control to the caller, the destructors for the members and bases are called. *[..]*

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's OK to end the execution of a destructor with a `return`.

Comment: Is there a source you can cite here, or some rationale regarding the same?

Comment: I was bases in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/destructors-cpp?view=vs-2017 @coldspeed, but the accepted edited answer is more analytical than mine, thus it should be on the spotlight, it deserves it.

Comment: There's no rule saying there should be just one good answer. The good thing about Stack Overflow is that I can upvote both your answers, not just one :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it is not only safe. The standard **explicitly** states that it is equivalent, and it explicitly gives destructors as one use case for empty return statements.

> **6.6.3 The return statement [stmt.return]**
>   1 A function returns to its caller by the return statement.
>   2 A return statement with neither an expression nor a braced-init-list can be used only in functions that do not return a value, that is, a function with the return type cv void, a constructor (12.1), **or a destructor** (12.4).
>   [...]
>   Flowing off the end of a function is **equivalent** to a return with no value

(Emphasis was added by me.)